# How to use a PHP object created inside a function outside of that function?

Tags: php, function

I am learning PHP and trying to wrap my head around both PHP and OOP. I've created this function to allow me to select which database to connect to and then create an object. I want to then use that object outside of the function to run queries, but I'm not quite sure how to do this. Here's what I've got:

```
function connectToDB($database) {
    switch($database) {
        case 'DB1':
            $host = DB1_HOST;
            $user = DB1_USER;
            $pw = DB1_PW;
            $dbname = DB1_NAME;
            $port = DB1_PORT;
            break;
        case 'DB2':
            $host = DB2_HOST;
            $user = DB2_USER;
            $pw = DB2_PW;
            $dbname = DB2_NAME;
            $port = DB2_PORT;
            break;
    }

    $db = new MySQLi;
    $db->connect($host, $user, $pw, $dbname, $port);
    return $db;
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is tell the function to either connect to 'DB1' or 'DB2', create a MySQLi object and make a database connection for that database, and then give me back the object ($db) so that I can do other things with it outside of the function, but I can't figure out how to get $db to exist outside of this function.

Comment: What you have should work, as you `return $db;`.  Outside it, you would need to do something like `$db = connectToDb('DB1');` to receive and assign the returned object... Is that where you're stuck?

Comment: That not OOP. If it was OOP, you'd have a class method rather than a function. Whatever, returning something *is* the way to make it available outside... given that you *read* the value when you call the function.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Ok, that's where I'm stuck. I was just doing connectToDB('DB1') by itself and then trying to use $db after it, thinking that running the function would create the object for me. Didn't realize I needed to create a new variable outside the function.

Comment: @Erick Yes, you need to create a variable outside the function, unless `$db` had been declared as `global` inside the function _which you SHOULD NOT do_. Returning it is the preferred way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `ConnectToDB()` returns an instance of MySQLi. You have to assign the returned instance to a variable. This can be done by doing:

```
$my_object = connectToDB('DB1') //in case of DB1
```

Then you can simply call the methods defined on the object in the following way:

```
$my_object->method_to_call();
```

In other words, you let a specific instance of a certain class (MySQLi) do some action, method_to_call() in this case.

Comment: Thanks! That was my problem. I was doing:
    connectToDB('DB1');
    echo var_dump($db);
Which resulted in $db being an undefined variable. I thought returning it just made it exist. Didn't realize I had to set a new variable outside of the function. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
$dbObj = connectToDB('DB1');
$dbObj->someFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods you could use. The one you are using should work as long as you are assigning the returned object to a variable. Another method would be to create the object somewhere else in a higher level class and then use the object variable in the connection method (this code probably doesn't work, it's just to illustrate the concept).

```
// declare database connection variable outside of functions in class 
private $db;
...

function init() {
   ...
   $this->db = new MySQLi; // or call this inside the connection function
}

function connectToDB($database) {
   $this->db->connect($host, $user, $pw, $dbname, $port);
}
```

Another method would be to pass the object in by reference to the function:

```
$db = new MySQLi;
function connectToDB($database, &$db) {
   // the & in front of the param indicates that it is passing in the original object by reference instead of making a copy in the local scope.
   $db->connect($host, $user, $pw, $dbname, $port);
   // since the object is passed in by reference, we don't need to return it
}
```